# JS - copy object from an array to the new one when the condition is met [edited]

Tags: javascript

What I have to do is filter the array and write selected elements in the new one. Previously I saw two possible ways, but thanks to comments bellow I realised that way with deleting elements from array is not good. So what I need to do is to copy some elements (i.e. everything with category "science") to new one. My first question is: which approach is better? more efficient? Thank you for your help! 
Now second question. How can I copy elements from my array to the new one? It was not a problem to copy only a book name form element with id 0. But when I was trying to copy id, name, category, price and image is exactly the same form to the new array the attempt failed...

My array is:

```js
var products =
    [
    {
        "id": "0",
        "name": "Book Name",
        "category": "science",
        "price": "$49,99",
        "image": "img/product-1.png"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Book Name 2",
        "category": "computers",
        "price": "$319",
        "image": "img/product-2.png"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Book Name 3",
        "category": ["science", "programming", "computers"],
        "price": "$49,99",
        "image": "img/product-1.png"
    }
]
```

below I tried to remove mismatched elements, but this approach turned out to be less effective and more problematic.

```js
let checkedOperations = 'programming';
let selected_products = [... products];

$(document).ready(function () {
  for (var i in products) {
    if (isTrue(checkedOperations, products[i].category)) {
      selected_products.splice(i,1);
    }
    console.log('selected products after slice -1 = ' + selected_products[1].name);
    console.log('selected products after slice  = ' + selected_products[2].name);
    console.log('selected products after slice +1 = ' + selected_products[3].name);
  }
});
```

Comment: Arrays are offset based, meaning their index starts at 0.  So your console.log part ranging from 1-3 seems like a problem

Comment: Also even if the index were correct, if you remove an element from the array, one of your console log statements will blow up with an error as you try to reference a name element on an undefined variable

Comment: Yes i see what you mean. My array is longer, so it's not a problem. I'm using a log to check if something has been deleted. But unfortunately not

Comment: although in fact if in the "for" loop I delete an element with index "i" all subsequent elements will reduce their index by 1, so in next iteration one element will be skipped and at the end not all elements will be searched. It would be better to write filtered element into the new array, the question is how can I do it in my case of such array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `forEach` should do the trick without handling indexes and thus making it less error-prone.

```
let resArray = []; // Filtered result array
products.forEach((el) => {
  if (el.id === "0") { // Whatever condition you want
    resArray.push(el);
  }
})
```